# jQuery - How to animate the box-shadow property?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

The below code is trying to animate the box-shadow css property.

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).animate(function() {
    box-shadow: "10px 10px 0 0 green", //does not work
    boxShadow: "10px 10px 0 0 green", //does not work
    boxshadowX: "200px" //does not work
  });
});
```

The above code does not work. Is it possible to animate the box-shadow property inside the animate function? If it is not possible what other alternatives can do the same?

Answer (score 3):

First of all your syntax is wrong.

Second, It is only possible to animate numeric values using `animate()` in jQuery. An alternative can be

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
        box-shadow: "10px 10px 0 0 green", 
        boxShadow: "10px 10px 0 0 green", 
        boxshadowX: "200px"
    });
});
```

then in your CSS

```
button
{
    transition: all .8s;   /* add vendor prefixes*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Please confirm if jquery animate takes only numeric values

Comment: @ Anubhav - the prop-val can take "height: "toggle"". and toggle is a string, not a numeric value. SO might not be right to say only numeric values, thought internally toggle might be coercing itself to a number. right?

Comment: When you use `animate()` you can only use numbers to make the element transition into those numbers for example `left: 20px` will make the element animate 20px to the left from its current position. Now `toggle` is a built in keyword in jQuery. If you use `height: 'toggle'`, definitely it would work as jQuery already recognizes it. No other string can be used as such.

Answer (score 0):

this fiddle might help you.this is somewhat related to my problem few day ago.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function(){   
   $(this).toggleClass("click");

});
```

});

see this demo

http://jsfiddle.net/TUFPU/6/